# How to I get the api. before my website link

Tags: mobile-website

Say my website is website.com
How do I get **api.**website.com

Is there a way to do this or do I need to buy another domain?

I have tried everything and can’t seem to find a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for subdomains. There is no need to buy another domain. You can check out this blog here for full details. https://in.godaddy.com/help/what-is-a-subdomain-296